# Computation of out-of-sample error

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, out-of-sample

I have a question on how one would theoretically compute the out of sample error of a given hypothesis in a data learning problem. I've been working through *Learning From Data: A Short Course* (http://amlbook.com), and in the introductory chapter, the out of sample error of a hypothesis $h:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is defined as follows:

$$E_{out}(h) = P[h(\mathbf{x}) \neq f({\mathbf{x}}) ]$$

Where $f:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ is the target function mapping inputs $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$ to the output space $\mathcal{Y}$.  The book states that this quantity depends on the particular probability distribution over $\mathcal{X}$ that is relevant to the problem.  My question is, given some known probability distribution (i.e. a density function $p(\mathbf{x}): \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), and assuming you *know* the target function $f$ and the hypothesis $h$, how would you go about computing this quantity?  Is there even a way to do so in general, or does the specific distribution need to be known?

I realize this is not very practical of a question, but I'm just having a hard time conceptualizing this quantity and seeing how it might be computed may help me understand the statement better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the density $p$, then evaluating $E_\text{out}$ amounts to integrating $p$ over the sub-region of $\mathcal{X}$ where $h(\mathbf{x}) \neq f(\mathbf{x})$. For a very simple example, suppose $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y} = \{0, 1\}$, and define $h$, $f$, and $p$ as follows:

| $\mathbf{x}$ | $h(\mathbf{x})$ | $f(\mathbf{x})$ | $p(\mathbf{x})$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1/3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2/3 |

Then hopefully it's clear that $E_\text{out}(h) = 1/3$. In practice, $p$ is generally unknown, and $E_\text{out}$ is instead estimated by collecting a test set and counting the number of examples where $h(\mathbf{x}) \neq f(\mathbf{x})$.